# Bind second recyclerview from the Onclick of another Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two recycler views. Each with their own adapter. The second is more or less a ditto of the first though has a different name and arraylist. I'm trying to bind the second one from the onclick of the first one, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView,recycler_view2;
    public CopMyAdapter adapter;
    public CopMyAdapterChild adapterchild;
    public List<CopListdata> coplistdata=new ArrayList<CopListdata>();
    public List<CopListdata>coplistdatachild= new ArrayList<CopListdata>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn= findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
             public void onClick(View v){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's magic",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.bringToFront();
    coplistdata=CopData.LoadDataCopButton();
    adapter=new CopMyAdapter(coplistdata,MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    recycler_view2 =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
    recycler_view2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    recycler_view2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_view2.bringToFront();
    coplistdatachild=CopData.LoadDataCopChildButton();
    adapterchild=new CopMyAdapterChild(coplistdatachild,MainActivity.this);
    recycler_view2.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recycler_view2.setAdapter(adapterchild);    }
         });
    }
}
```

Here is my first adapter where I want to bind to the second Recyclerview. You will see toward the bottom where my `onClick()` is for the first `RecyclerView`.  I'm pretty sure I can do this though I am just struggling with how.  Specifically with the syntax of doing this as well.  Essentially I want to take the recycler_view2 block, as seen in the `MainActivity`, and insert it into the `onClick()` section of the first adapter.

CopMyAdapter.java

```
public class CopMyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CopMyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CopListdata> copitems;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView fooditem;
    public ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        fooditem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fooditem);
        constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerlayout);
    }
}
public CopMyAdapter(List<CopListdata> copitems, Context context) {
    this.copitems = copitems;
    this.context = context;
}

private Context context;

@Override
public CopMyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recylerview_main, parent, false);

    // Return a new holder instance
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final CopListdata coplistdata = copitems.get(position);

    holder.fooditem.setText(coplistdata.get_itemname());

    holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"you clicked child "+coplistdata.get_itemname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  .show();

//  **** This is where I want to bind my second Reycler view.   *******************

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return copitems.size();
}
}
```

Comment: you have set both recycleview in  your button click . so what you really want to do ?

Comment: attach it to the onclick of the first recycler view, when user clicks recyclerview I want to open and make visible the second.- see above where the toast is in the adapter, this is where I want this to happen.

public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"you clicked child

How do I bind the second one and show

Comment: show and display the second recyclerview, recyclerview_2, when you click a record in the first one.
- see above where the toast is in the adapter, this is where I want this to happen.
Hope this helps explain ...thanks

Comment: attach your activity_main.xml and  by attaching two recycleview in one activity what you want to do actually ?

Comment: I understand I have the second recyclerview on the first button and that's incorrect - that's what I'm wanting to fix.  How and where do I implement the second recycler view. I have the onClick setup in the 'OnBindViewHolder of the first adapter.  Is it here that I create the object for the second Recycler view and create and set it's adapter.  If it is how do I do that?  I apologize if I'm not explaining myself well